# Frame buffer color in metal for Mac Applications

Tags: metal, metal-performance-shaders

[image]How can i read frame buffer current color in my shader for mac application.
I am very easily to do same thing in ios app using [[color(0)]].

I tried using texture as shown below, some pixels are getting missed.

texture2d_array normal_1 [[texture(0)]]

SampleCode

```
fragment float4 funcname(QuadFragIn     inFrag [[ stage_in ]],
                                  texture2d_array<float> normal_1 [[texture(0)]])
{



    float4 color_0 = float4(normal_1.sample(tex_sampler, inFrag.m_TexCoord, 0));
    float4 color_1 = float4(normal_1.sample(tex_sampler, inFrag.m_TexCoord, 1));
    float4 color_2 = float4(normal_1.sample(tex_sampler, inFrag.m_TexCoord, 2));

    int index = inFrag.index;

    if(index == 0)
    {
        return color_0;
    }
    else if(index == 1)
    {
        return color_1;
    }
    else
    {
        return color_2;
    }

}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

In the output file attach, the white strip is the concerned issue.

Answer (score 1):

As per Metal shading language specification (https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf, comments under Table 12)

> For `[[color(m)]]`, m is used to specify the color attachment index when accessing (reading or
>   writing) multiple color attachments in a fragment function. The `[[color(m)]]` attribute is only
>   supported in iOS.

That means that you can't do pixel readback (reading already rendererd pixels from attached texture in the same render pass).

One way to avoid having to do pixel readback is doing pixel writes and reads in separate render passes: you render what you want in first render pass and then attach the result of the first render pass as a texture, which you can sample or just read.